# Is there some sort of limitation in Google Analytics being capped at 20 consecutive events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

i got a code when user click download all, it sends custom event to GTM for every file in the folder.

e.g. User clicks download all and the folder has 30 files.

I got a loop that sends consecutive events to GTM and i can see that 30 events are being received in preview in Google Tag Manager.

```
filesInFolder.forEach((file) => {
    window.dataLayer.push({
        event: "file_download",
        file_name: file.name,
        ...
    })
})
```

also confirmed that GTM passes 30 events to GA.

But in GA debug view. only receives 20 events max.

is there some sort of limit in Google Analytics? I've been reading everywhere and trying to find documentations. but i couldn't find anything about this. or is this only because its implemented through Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0):

> Each gtag.js and analytics.js tracker object starts with 20 hits that are replenished at a rate of 2 hits per second. This limit applies to all hits except for ecommerce (item or transaction).

source:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas#analyticsjs